# Can Schengen Visa of Germany be used to visit Italy

Tags: schengen

I have a multiple entry Schengen Visa issued by Germany for business meetings, but the meeting got cancelled.

Now I want to travel to Italy on holidays. Can I use my German Schengen Visa altough I have not entered Germany with this visa?

Or do I have to apply for a separate Schengen Visa from the Italian Embassy?

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically you can, **but** your primary purpose of the visit is no longer applicable and you are going to a different country for a different purpose than initially stated (and never utilized) .

There are significant chances that you may be refused entry unless you put up a strong case and are lucky.

I would **apply afresh** at the Italian Embassy.